# problems performing filter on summed values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a WHERE filter in the field where I am summing the values.

WHERE accumulated > 50000 . Is not being accepted. Anyone know why?

```
    SELECT SUM (value) as accumulated, id_motorist FROM trip WHERE accumulated > 50000 
    GROUP by id_motorista
```

Comment: what you mean by not being accepted? is there any error or you are not able to get the desired result. And group by might be the one changing your result.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Group by** you need to use **having** instead.

Like that:

```
SELECT SUM (value) as accumulated, id_motorist FROM trip GROUP by id_motorista HAVING accumulated > 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to filter groups based on the value of an aggregate function (sum), so you should use having instead of where.

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM (value) as accumulated, id_motorist 
FROM trip
GROUP by id_motorista
HAVING sum(value)  > 50000
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check manual that corrsponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near 'GROUP by id_motorista' at line 3

Comment: Sorry, forgot the having should be after the group by, it should work now